# How do I access instance of a many-to-many field in django __str__ method

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am having two models;

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="book")
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1, null=True, blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.quantity} of {self.book.title}"

class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cart = models.ManyToManyField(Cart)
    
    def __str__(self):
       return f"{self.cart.quantity}"
```

I get:

```
'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'quantity'
```

This usually works for a `ForeignKey` field; but it seems not to for a `ManyToManyField`.

Note: I am trying to access quantity that belongs to the cart model from the Order model using `ManyToManyField`.

Is there any way of doing something like this?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.cart` returns '`ManyRelatedManager`'.

you have to write something like this:

```
self.cart.last().quantity 
# OR
self.cart.first().quantity
```

or get sum of all, with `self.cart.all()`

```
sum([_.quantity for _ in self.cart.all()])
```